# Sort big array into smaller by value in objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have large array, which looks like this:

```
let arr = [{
           'name': '1',
           'val': '12'
          },{
           'name': '4',
           'val': '52'
          },
          {
           'name': '11',
           'val': '15'
          },
          {
           'name': '4',
           'val': '33'
          },
          ...]
```

I want find all objects with same `name` values and push them into separated arrays . 
P.S. I don't know possible `name` values in array.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal separated arrays of objects with same `name`.

Comment: @VladimirHumeniuk the actual output values?

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal yes, i want just find objects with same names and push them into new arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily group by name to get what you need. Below is a quite general function to group any array of objects to a Map, by specified property. Then simply make it an array and you're done

```js
function group(arr, propertyToGroupBy) {
  return arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a.set(b[propertyToGroupBy], (a.get(b[propertyToGroupBy]) || []).concat(b));
  }, new Map);
}

const map = group(arr, 'name');

console.log(Array.from(map));
```

```html
<script>
  let arr = [{
      'name': '1',
      'val': '12'
    }, {
      'name': '4',
      'val': '52'
    },
    {
      'name': '11',
      'val': '15'
    },
    {
      'name': '4',
      'val': '33'
    }
  ];
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group your array based on `name` in an object accumulator. Then using `Object.values()` you can get all the values.

```js
let arr = [{ 'name': '1', 'val': '12' },{ 'name': '4', 'val': '52' }, { 'name': '11', 'val': '15' }, { 'name': '4', 'val': '33' }],
    result = Object.values(arr.reduce((r,o) => {
      r[o.name] = r[o.name] || [];
      r[o.name].push(o);
      return r;
    },{}));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr=[{'name':'1','val':'12'},{'name':'4','val':'52'},{'name':'11','val':'15'},{'name':'4','val':'33'}];

let groups = arr.reduce((obj, el) => ({...obj, [el.name]: [...obj[el.name] || [], el] }), {});

console.log(groups);
```

Answer (score 0):

Group with `reduce` and map out the output to be an array:

```
let arr = [{'name': '1','val': '12'},{'name': '4','val': '52'}, {'name': '11','val': '15'},{'name': '4','val': '33'}];

// group object by same name
const dataObj = arr.reduce((all, {name, val}) => {

    if (!all.hasOwnProperty(name)) all[name] = [];
    all[name].push({name, val});
    return all;

}, {});

// map out the result into an array
const result = Object.keys(dataObj).map(k => (dataObj[k]));

console.log(result);
```